# Running Test on Flutter shows 'Error: No Bazel Target Set'

Tags: android, dart, flutter

While running test on android studio one dialog box called Edit configuration opens with error "No Bazel Target Set".
 Here is the screenshot[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a known issue that should be fixed already

https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/3169

Updating the plugin version should fix it.

You need to re-create the launch configuration.
Deleting it and selecting "run" on the test file should do though.